# Where can 2-factor fail in Google?

Tags: multi-factor

I was one of the people who thought that enabling 2-factor in Apple would have prevented the download of images from iCloud; it was recently pointed out to me that, in fact, I was gravely mistaken. Apple's 2-factor only works in a subset of their services and therefore their 2-factor lends a false sense of security (at this point; they may extend the services their 2-factor protects at some point.)

I had thought the implementation was similar to Google's 2-factor. Are there ways that Google's 2-factor implementation is similarly bypassed, where there are services or circumstances I would not be alerted if my account were accessed by a machine or device not in my control?

Answer (score 3):

Here's some scenarios where Google's 2FA implementation might be compromised:

- [App specific passwords](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en) do not require 2FA even if 2FA is enabled on the account. Therefore a malicious App which has been provided an App specific password can perform actions without your knowledge.
- On Android the Authenticator App does not contain an internal QR code reader, instead it creates an implicit Intent and allows any App with an appropriate Intent filter to receive the intent. This App could be malicious or act as a MITM to a legitimate QR code reader.
- 2FA is not entirely immune to phishing. If an attacker can convince you to enter both your password and a valid 2FA pin then they can potentially log in then create an App specific password to use as a back door.
- There is an option to receive [2FA codes via phone call](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185834?hl=en#nocode). The phone call can potentially go to voicemail which is [notoriously](http://blog.cloudflare.com/the-four-critical-security-flaws-that-resulte) [insecure](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/04/24/voicemail_still_easy_to_hack/).
- An attacker can [also use SMS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IFptQ.png) and it's relatively sneaky to slip permissions to access SMS past users on Android in particular.

Answer (score 0):

Google's 2 factor authentication requires a password and an alternate method of verification such as phone call or text message. A password being compromised is the standard issue. That being the reason for two-factor verification. So assuming that your password was compromised, then focus on the second part: If someone has stolen your cell phone then phone messaging or a call would be compromised.

A few years ago I had a phone that got cloned. What happened is that the cloned phone received the same calls and messages that the main one did.

Password theft is a potential problem if combined with theft of a cell phone. Google informs people of this however during signup for the procedure.

Two-Factor Verification makes it harder, but not perfect.

Check this article for a report by a person in Australia who has found many things about multiple forms of 2-Factor issues with many companies including Google. http://shubh.am/how-i-bypassed-2-factor-authentication-on-google-yahoo-linkedin-and-many-others/#google

Comment: But are there services or methods of access that bypass 2-factor? That's what happens with Apple's implementation of 2-fac.

Comment: Not according to the news this week... PC Magazine September 3, 2014: Apple today said that the hack of celebrity photos did not include a breach of iCloud or Find My iPhone.
Instead, "certain celebrity accounts were compromised by a very targeted attack on user names, passwords, and security questions, a practice that has become all too common on the Internet," Apple said in a statement.

Comment: This is what you are talking about right?

Comment: Their two factor is completely bypassed with certain methods. http://techcrunch.com/2014/09/02/apples-two-factor-authentication-doesnt-protect-icloud-backups-or-photo-streams/

Comment: That is about the same issue yes, the article TechCrunch refers to shows Apple staunchly denying anything other than simple Identity Theft/Password Phishing... TechCrunch gives an example where the backups are not protected by that Two Factor method.

Comment: Right; you have 2-factor enabled, but people can still get access to your data without notification.

Is there similar loopholes with Google drive, calendar, mail, etc...

Comment: +1 for the good response with example article, keeping people informed of possible concerns is one of the main reasons this board exists!

Comment: Added more in Edits... see my revised answer...